# How to get and manipulate values from multi dimensional array and display them in row wise

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
array(2) { 
    ["storeData"]=> array(10) { 
        [0]=> array(18) { 
            ["name"]=> string(7) "STORENAME 01" 
            ["address"]=> string(19) "THIS IS ADDRESS 01"
            ["zip"]=> string(5) "33312" 
            ["pricing"]=> array(1) {
                [0]=> array(4) { 
                    ["price"]=> float(30.00) 
                } 
            } 
            ["distance"]=> float(3.0000) 

        }
        [1]=> array(18) { 
            ["name"]=> string(7) "STORENAME 02" 
            ["address"]=> string(19) "THIS IS ADDRESS 02"
            ["zip"]=> string(5) "33302" 
            ["pricing"]=> array(1) {
                [0]=> array(4) { 
                    ["price"]=> float(35.00) 
                } 
            } 
            ["distance"]=> float(2.0000) 
        }
        [2]=> array(18) { 
            ["name"]=> string(7) "STORENAME 01" 
            ["address"]=> string(19) "SAME STORE BUT AT DIFFERENT LOCATION"
            ["zip"]=> string(5) "33301" 
            ["pricing"]=> array(1) {
                [0]=> array(4) { 
                    ["price"]=> float(30.00) 
                } 
            } 
            ["distance"]=> float(3.5000) 
        }
     }
}
```

I want to make so
#1 - store name will display only once if there are more than one stores with same name.
#2 - Than all addresses of same store should display with that store.
#3 - Same store at different locations will have same price so price should display only once.
#4 - Want to display all above info row wise (using loop)

I tried following but not working properly. It gives me similar store names only once and gives different locations for that store too. But price is not displaying only once for each unique store name.

```
$cnt = 1; 
if (is_array($json) && !empty($json))
{
    foreach ($json as $key1 => $level1)
    {
        if (is_array($level1) && !empty($level1))
        {
            foreach ($level1 as $key2 => $level2)
            {
                if($cnt == 1)
                {
                    $str_name = $level2['name'];
                    echo "----- ".$level2['name']." -----<br/>";
                }
                if($str_name == $level2['name'])
                {
                    echo $level2['address']." - ";
                    echo $level2['zip']." - ";
                }
                else if($str_name != $level2['name'])
                {
                    $str_name = $level2['name'];
                    echo "----- ".$level2['name']." -----<br/>";

                    echo $level2['address']." - ";
                    echo $level2['zip']." - ";
                }

                if (is_array($level2) && !empty($level2))
                {
                    foreach ($level2 as $key3 => $level3)
                    {
                        if (is_array($level3) && !empty($level3))
                        {
                            foreach ($level3 as $key4 => $level4)
                            {
                                if($cnt == 1)
                                {
                                    echo "<b>".$level4['price']."</b> <br/>";
                                }

                                if($str_name != $level2['name'])
                                {
                                    echo "<b>".$level4['price']."</b> <br/>";
                                }                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                $cnt++;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So what changes should I do in my above to make it work as I mentioned above? Or please suggest completely different solution(s) if this is not going to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not saying your code wont work but for me it is quite complex for what it is trying to solve.
I would split this task into 2 phases: 1. transform data to format you need. 2. Display the data as you see fit.

```
<?php
$data = [
    "storeData"=> [ 
        0=> [ 
            "name"=>"STORENAME 01", 
            "address"=> "THIS IS ADDRESS 01",
            "zip"=> "33312", 
            "pricing"=> [
                0=> [ 
                    "price"=> 30.00, 
                ], 
            ], 
            "distance"=> 3.0000, 

        ],
        1=> [ 
            "name"=> "STORENAME 02", 
            "address"=> "THIS IS ADDRESS 02",
            "zip"=> "33302", 
            "pricing"=> [
                0=> [ 
                    "price"=> 35.00, 
                ],
            ], 
            "distance"=> 2.0000, 
        ],
        2=> [ 
            "name"=> "STORENAME 01", 
            "address"=> "SAME STORE BUT AT DIFFERENT LOCATION",
            "zip"=> "33301", 
            "pricing"=> [
                0=> [ 
                    "price"=> 30.00, 
                ], 
            ], 
            "distance"=> 3.5000, 
        ],
     ],
];

// 1. transform to what is needed
$stores = [];
foreach ($data['storeData'] as $store) {
  if (!isset($stores[$store['name']])) {
    $stores[$store['name']] = ['name' => $store['name'], 'price' => $store['pricing'][0]['price'], 'locations'=>[$store['address'] => ['address' => $store['address'], 'zip' => $store['zip']]]];
  } else {
    $stores[$store['name']]['locations'][$store['address']] = ['address' => $store['address'], 'zip' => $store['zip']];
  }
}

var_dump($stores);

// 2. display
foreach ($stores as $store) {
  echo 'store: '.$store['name'].PHP_EOL;
  echo '  locations:'.PHP_EOL;
  foreach ($store['locations'] as $location) {
    echo '    '.$location['address'].' '.$location['zip'].PHP_EOL;
  }
  echo '  price: '.$store['price'].PHP_EOL;
}
```

This is the `$stores` variable:

```
array(2) {
  ["STORENAME 01"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "STORENAME 01"
    ["price"]=>
    float(30)
    ["locations"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["THIS IS ADDRESS 01"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["address"]=>
        string(18) "THIS IS ADDRESS 01"
        ["zip"]=>
        string(5) "33312"
      }
      ["SAME STORE BUT AT DIFFERENT LOCATION"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["address"]=>
        string(36) "SAME STORE BUT AT DIFFERENT LOCATION"
        ["zip"]=>
        string(5) "33301"
      }
    }
  }
  ["STORENAME 02"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "STORENAME 02"
    ["price"]=>
    float(35)
    ["locations"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["THIS IS ADDRESS 02"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["address"]=>
        string(18) "THIS IS ADDRESS 02"
        ["zip"]=>
        string(5) "33302"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It is exacly what you requested: each entry is a store, each store has all locations, single price.

Now it can be displayed as you want (html, console output etc. I used console output and got):

```
store: STORENAME 01
  locations:
    THIS IS ADDRESS 01 33312
    SAME STORE BUT AT DIFFERENT LOCATION 33301
  price: 30
store: STORENAME 02
  locations:
    THIS IS ADDRESS 02 33302
  price: 35
```

If you want html replace `PHP_EOL` with `<br />`

Edit: code without location addresses as keys:

```
// transform to what is needed
$stores = [];
foreach ($data['storeData'] as $store) {
  if (!isset($stores[$store['name']])) {
    $stores[$store['name']] = ['name' => $store['name'], 'price' => $store['pricing'][0]['price'], 'locations'=> [['address' => $store['address'], 'zip' => $store['zip']]]];
  } else {
    $stores[$store['name']]['locations'][] = ['address' => $store['address'], 'zip' => $store['zip']];
  }
}
```

`$stores`:

```
array(2) {
  ["STORENAME 01"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "STORENAME 01"
    ["price"]=>
    float(30)
    ["locations"]=>
    array(2) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["address"]=>
        string(18) "THIS IS ADDRESS 01"
        ["zip"]=>
        string(5) "33312"
      }
      [1]=>
      array(2) {
        ["address"]=>
        string(36) "SAME STORE BUT AT DIFFERENT LOCATION"
        ["zip"]=>
        string(5) "33301"
      }
    }
  }
  ["STORENAME 02"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(12) "STORENAME 02"
    ["price"]=>
    float(35)
    ["locations"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      array(2) {
        ["address"]=>
        string(18) "THIS IS ADDRESS 02"
        ["zip"]=>
        string(5) "33302"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, I am trying above code but having one doubt in var_dump where address itself displaying as key name (3001 N STATE ROAD 7) as showing here  :  array(1) { ["WALMART"]=> array(3) { ["name"]=> string(7) "WALMART" ["price"]=> float(31.14) ["locations"]=> array(5) { ["3001 N STATE ROAD 7"]  => array(2) { ["address"]=> string(19) "3001 N STATE ROAD 7" ["zip"]=> string(5) "33313" }

Comment: Its not needed if you dont have to check for duplicate addresses for stores but also it is not used in rendering later. You can remove keys in locations to just have numeric values if you want.

Comment: Anyway, added an edit with code without addresses as keys if for some reason this is an issue for you.

Comment: Ty for both solutions and it is working as I requested in my question. Is it possible to sort this same array result according to zip? Currently it is sorted (ascending) according to price. Please let me know.

Comment: If it works for you consider accepting the answer. Yes it is possible but do you want to keep the order of stores, but sort the locations based on zip inside each store? You can always use usort function, something like this `usort($locations, function($a, $b) {return $a['zip'] - $b['zip'];});` on every locations array (foreach store)

Comment: I want to keep array data same as they are currently now. Store name and price will display only once and all locations for same store will be listed. Currently lowest price data displays first. Instead of that I want to display listing according to ascending order of zipcode. Please let me know if I am explaining properly.

Comment: But price is the same for the store and all its locations, but each location has its zip code. Do you want to leave stores in the order they are right now and sort locations in each of them separately? Lest say: Store 1: location zip: 3, 1. Store 2: location zip: 5, 2, 4. You want to have Store 1 first, and locations in that store with zip 1,3 and then Store 2 with locations 2, 4, 5?

Comment: Hi, Your above answer is working superb. Now I want to sort all zip codes for each store in ascending order. Please let me know how I can do it or update it in your answer. Ty